# Microsoft LifeCam VX3000 no longer works on 18.04

Tags: usb, 18.04, vlc, camera, cheese

My Microsoft LifeCam VX3000 no longer works on 18.04 using Cheese. Worked before with 16.40
Microphone is fine but no video.
No image on Skype either.
I can see the camera on "lsusb".
VLC error: "VLC is unable to open the MRL 'v4l2:///dev/video0'
log:
v4l2 error: cannot set format: Device or resource busy
v4l2 error: not a radio tuner device
v4l2 error: cannot set format: Device or resource busy
But works fine on Camorama.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Works pefectly (better than on m$ ;-). All you need to do is to add user to group 'video'.
My `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 045e:00f5 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam VX-3000
```

Comment: That did not work. Video group does not exist. Is one expected to be present without user interference?

Comment: I installed default desktop installation of 18.04, Kubuntu. It is very strange you do not have video group. I have checked - also on regular 18.04 i have video group on desktop installation.